# SVN issue on MAC

Tags: svn, netbeans, javahl

I am getting this error on Mac but not on my Windows.

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E170001: Authorization failed

can anybody help?

Update,

I have installed Versions 1.3 and it worked properly. But still Netbeans SVN and SmartSVN doesn't work. have anybody encountered this?

Comment: Show us the complete wording of the error. It looks like it's only the first part of the error. And make sure that you use up-to-date Subversion client.

Comment: that's the complete message, I am using SVN inside netbeans latest version

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there should be some kind of a button like "See more" to reveal the complete wording. If "Authorization failed" is the only error you can see, then I guess that this is a NetBeans bug just because it is impossible to effectively troubleshoot this without knowing the last part of the error.

I'm asking for the complete message because there can be many reasons to getting this error. But most likely is that your user account does not have permissions to access the repository. Therefore, authorization fails and you see this error.

However, "Authorization failed" error can be also seen when you can't authenticate to the server. In such case this problem is unrelated to repository permissions. Do you use Integrated Windows Authentication on the server maybe (i.e. Active Directory Single Sign-On)? Is your OSX machine joined to your AD domain?

If you get this error on OSX only but not on Windows (your question is unclear about this), then I suggest contacting your system / Subversion server administrator for assistance with this issue.

Comment: I have updated my question it's working properly on windows, note that I am connecting on a VPN before accessing the svn repo, which is working properly on windows